# In Google Slides, how to remove a text block from all slides at once?

Tags: google-slides

I have a slide deck that has a "footer" element on every single slide, rather than just on the Master slide.  I've fixed this by using the Master slide, but now I have to remove this footer element from nearly 200 slides.

Is there any way to remove this repeated block from every slide at once?  Find/Replace doesn't work as I end up with "Unsupported Placeholder" on every page instead.

Answer (score 1):

Seems this is not possible.  I ended up just manually going through every single slide and deleting the block in question.  Tedious but at least it's done.